# Open CV 3.1.0 for Java java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, opencv

I installed opencv 3.1.0 from source files and try a sample code
http://answers.opencv.org/question/68037/opencv-3-java-face-recognition-example-requested/ .

However,

```
  CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(
       "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"
  );
```

returns an error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:31)
at FaceDetectorTest.main(FaceDetectorTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I do

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

before the CascadeClassifier and it does not return any error (it looks)

Comment: Are you calling `new CascadeClassifier` before `System.loadLibrary()` ?

Comment: No, I try to create CascadeClassifier after System.loadLibrary().

Comment: did you set native library opencv-3.1.0.dll in your project ?

Comment: yes, I did. but still i got the same messages